# How to change CS in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I would like to know how it is possible to access CS, Since I know this is impossible to do MOV CS, SOME_VALUE.
my question is how the loader can load something to CS. Should I use the IP?

Comment: Use a far jump.

Comment: For example. let's assume I have in the main some code. how is it possible to load it to the CS can you explain?

Comment: You want to load code into CS? That makes no sense.

Comment: I want to understand what I should do instead of MOV CS, SOMEVALUE because this is illegal.

Comment: "use the far jump" was the first comment. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp ... that said, make sure you have code in the target code segment ready to be executed, because obviously the jump will jump there. You can't load `cs` with some "value" like any value, as the CPU is using `cs:ip` for every next instruction fetch, so the `cs` must point all the time to the memory segment where your running code is. (or more precise is: "where-ever the `cs` points, there the CPU continues to execute instructions, even if there is garbage instead of regular code")

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation.